# Display wait cursor when 'Next' clicked - Netbeans WizardDescriptor

Tags: java, swing, cursor, netbeans-platform, glasspane

I have a Wizard Iterator with a few PanelDescriptors. 
I'm trying to display a Wait Cursor when 'Next' is clicked on one PanelDescriptor which implements WizardDescriptor.ValidatingPanel. The validate() method in that takes time execute.

So far I've tried few ways, non of them works for me.

1. http://dev.platform.netbeans.narkive.com/ofiffInN/finally-a-waitcursor-routine-that-works-in-netbeans
2. http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Setting-wait-cursor-td3026613.html#a3026614

   ```
   private static void changeCursorWaitStatus(final boolean isWaiting) {
       Mutex.EVENT.writeAccess(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   JFrame mainFrame = (JFrame) WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
                   Component glassPane = mainFrame.getGlassPane();
                   if (isWaiting) {
                       glassPane.setVisible(true);
                       glassPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
                   } else {
                       glassPane.setVisible(false);
                       glassPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   // probably not worth handling 
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. https://community.oracle.com/message/5322657#5322657

   ```
   try {            
       TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
       doBusyStuff();
   } finally {
       TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated().setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
   }
   ```

Any hint to point me in the right direction would appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    private static final java.awt.event.MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

    };

    protected static final Cursor READY_CSR = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
    protected static final Cursor WAIT_CSR  = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);

    public void setBusy(boolean busy) {

        if(busy) {
            setCursor(WAIT_CSR);
            frame.getGlassPane().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
            frame.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
            frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        }else {
            setCursor(READY_CSR);
            frame.getGlassPane().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            frame.getGlassPane().removeMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
            frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [First link](http://dev.platform.netbeans.narkive.com/ofiffInN/finally-a-waitcursor-routine-that-works-in-netbeans)  contains solution like this and it doesn't work in my case.